# What does $P[(X > 6)/(X > 5)]$ mean? (not | but /)

Tags: probability, notation

In a book, I'm in front of:
$P[(X > 6) / (X > 5)]$

What does it mean?
$X > 6$ knowing $X > 5$?
I would have expected it like $P[(X > 6)|(X > 5)]$, then
with a |, not a /, so I believe that I'm misleading, and that what I see isn't what I believe.

---

Sorry, eventually it appears to be really only a division of $P(X > 6)$ by $P(X > 5)$.

I don't see the use of such expression, but regarding to the solution of the exercise I was on, it's that.

Comment: I think "/" is just old school notation for what we typically se as "|" these days. I had a fairly old econometrics professor who used the same notation, but it definitely is far from standard.

Comment: But note that since the event $X>6$ is a subset of the event $X>5$, we have $P(X>6 | X > 5) = P((X>6) \& (X>5)) / P(X>5) = P(X>6) / P(X>5)$, which explains why the solution manual gives the answer it does.

Comment: How old is the textbook and was it formatted on a computer? In ancient times, the pipe symbol used for conditional probability displayed with a gap in it (like a "fat colon"), so the author may've used forward slash as a close approximation.

Comment: The speculation about slashes would be more persuasive if those parentheses weren't there.  The notation would be $\Pr(X\gt 6\ /\ X\gt 5].$  The presence of the parentheses suggests a typographical omission where $\Pr(X\gt 6)/\Pr(X\gt 5)$ was intended.